# How can I overload bitwise AND (&) in c++ that concatenates the left operand (const char []) with the right operand string object) (Homework)

Tags: c++

*EDIT*: The code that immediately follows, is the working version, located within the header

```
inline char * operator & (const char String1 [], const MyStringClass & String2)
{
    int length = strlen (String1) + String2.Length();
    char * pTemp = new char [length + 1];
    strcpy (pTemp, String1);
    strcat (pTemp, String2.GetStr());   
    return pTemp;
}
```

This is the first time I've felt the need to ask a question, since I've been unable to find helpful information on my own (via search, Google, book, etc). My course book is C++ Primer 5th Edition and I've read Ch. 14 which covers operator overloading. I'm not necessarily looking for an "answer" but rather a nudge in the right direction (because I do want to learn this stuff).

The assignment has us creating our own string class and overloading a bunch of operators that will take a class object on either side - with exception to the assignment operator which may only take a class object on the left side. I've played around with all sorts of return types (this cannot be a member function; efforts to make this a friend function failed).

```
/* 
   Note: return by value, otherwise I get a warning of returning the address
   of a local variable, temporary. But no matter the return type or what I'm
   returning, I always get the error: C2677: binary '&' : no global operator 
   found which takes type 'MyStringClass' (or there is no acceptable 
   conversion)
*/

MyStringClass operator & (const char String1 [], const MyStringClass & String2)
{
    /*
       The only requirement is that the left side has const char [] so that
       (const char []) & (MyStringClass &) will concatenate. There is no return 
       type requirement; so, I could either try and return a string object or
       an anonymous C-type string.

       cout << StringOject1 << endl; // this works
       cout << (StringObject1 & "bacon") << endl; // so does this; 
       // another function overloads & such that: obj & const char [] works

       cout << ("bacon" & StringObject1) << endl; // but not this
    */

    MyStringClass S (String1); // initialize a new object with String1
    S.Concat (String2); // public member function Concat() concatenates String2
                        // onto String1 in S
    return S; // this does not work

    /* a different way of trying this... */
    int Characters = strlen (String1) + String2.Length();
    int Slots = Characters;
    char * pTemp = new char [Slots + 1];
    strcpy (pTemp, String1);
    strcat (pTemp, String2.pString); // this won't work; pString is a private 
                                     // member holding char * and inaccessible
    // making it pointless to try and initialize and return an object with pTemp
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your prof likes to think that C++ is Excel.

Comment: Also show the code that attempts to use the operator function.

Comment: What does the comment "does not work" mean? Why do you think that line causes the problem? The error you post indicates a problem at the site where you try to use the operator.

Comment: Does [this](http://pastebin.com/bzjAmQcA) cause any errors with your compiler?

Comment: @aschepler I thought I did? cout << ("bacon" & StringObject1) << endl;

Comment: @n.m. Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class MyString__cdecl operator&(char const * const,class MyString const &)" (??I@YA?AVRSR_String@@QBDABV0@@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: There's nothing that looks remotely like `RSR_String` in my simple code. I have no idea what fuels your compiler's imagination. Check your project settings unwanted preprocessor definitions and the like.

Comment: @n.m. that was my failed attempt at obfuscating the actual name of my string class... :)

Comment: for the sake of being thorough, I continued getting the following error: error LNK2005: "char * __cdecl operator&(char const * const,class MyStringClass const &)" (??I@YAPADQBDABVRSR_String@@@Z) already defined in Main.obj
1>c:\users\----\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\----\Debug\----.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found and realized that simply adding the keyword inline within the header fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have looked at your code and from what I can understand, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
class MyStringClass
{
public:
    const char* data() const;

private:
const char* charptr;
};


const char* MyStringClass::data() const
{
    return charptr;
}


MyStringClass operator & (const char String1 [], const MyStringClass & String2)
{
    /* a different way of trying this... */
    int len = strlen(String1) + String2.Length();
    char * pTemp = new char [len + 1]; //total length of both strings
    strcpy (pTemp, String1);
    strcat (pTemp, String2.data()); // you need to have a public member function that returns the string as const char*
    MyStringClass str(pTemp); //requires MyStringClass to have constructor that takes char*
    return str; //return the string

}
```

Comment: This absolutely solves my problem; I guess I was searching for a way to make this work without using a public member function that returned the private string I needed... I do appreciate your time, and everyone else for the help.

Comment: How could `MyStringClass` be useful without a way to get its contents?  (If you heard the rule "Don't create public accessors for private members", add "... without thinking" or "... without a reason" or similar to the mantra.)